# Down Payment for new Company Car

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business, car, down-payment

Is there a limit on the amount a business can place on a down-payment for a business vehicle; in the United States of America?

> Total Cost: $25,000
>
> Estimated Down-payment: $10,000

Is it commonplace for businesses to put a large amount of money down for down-payments on cars?

Comment: Are you interested in the tax implications of buying or leasing? or is there some other question you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A business could buy the car outright for cash if it so chose, so no, there's no specific limit on the down payment.